# captcha error on jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, captcha

I have a captcha on my JSP form , but the response always enter in the wrong condition never enter in the wright one

here my jsp code:

```
<%@ page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptcha" %>
<%@ page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaFactory" %>
<form action="captchaVerif" method="post" class="register modalReg" role="form">

         <!-- CAPTCHA -->
         <div class="g-recaptcha" data- sitekey="6LcxQB8TAAAAANn08BYWSRspvQjH_5fEqPnXSHin"></div>
         <!-- CAPTCHA -->
         <button value="reg" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg-btn-block">S'inscrire</button>
      </form>
```

and here my servlet :

```
String remoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();
    ReCaptchaImpl reCaptcha = new ReCaptchaImpl();
    reCaptcha.setPrivateKey("6LcxQB8TAAAAAKkXkR4UwtE--L1VwgMQkwGf6Mga");

    String challenge = request.getParameter("recaptcha_challenge_field");
    String uresponse = request.getParameter("recaptcha_response_field");
    ReCaptchaResponse reCaptchaResponse = reCaptcha.checkAnswer(remoteAddr, challenge, uresponse);

    if (reCaptchaResponse.isValid()) {
        response.sendRedirect("inscription.jsp"); //doesn't enter here
    } 
    if (!reCaptchaResponse.isValid()){
      processRequest(request, response); //always enter here 
    }
```

I can't find where is the error ?

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint and check that the correct values are making it from your UI to the server side?

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand what do you mean, i folowed this tutorials http://javapapers.com/core-java/captcha-in-java-using-recaptcha/

Comment: Why is the private key different for the JSP and the servlet code?

Comment: on the jsp we put the client key but on the servlet we put the private one

Comment: The tutorial uses the same key on client and server.  I don't know for certain if this be the cause of your problem, q.v. my answer below.

Comment: there are 2 annotations for client side i used both and it doesn't work

Comment: of corse cause reCaptcha gives 2 keys one for the client side the other for server side they are different, when signing up on reCaptcha https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html it gives them both

Comment: You need to step through your code and determine the error.  I upvoted you, good luck.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen thanks